# Lazy Loaded List with Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to build something like a lazy loaded list with Firebase, meaning I load an initial 10 items or something like that, whenever the user scrolls to the bottom of the list, I load 10 more items.

I have two problems:

1. How do I know when the user has scrolled to the bottom?
2. How do I update a query most effectively?

I currently query like this:

```
  List myItems;
  BehaviorSubject myItemsSubject = new BehaviorSubject();
  int currentlyLoadedItems = 10;

  // I call this in my constructor:
  loadItems() {
    Firestore.instance.collection('MyCollection').orderBy('position', descending: true).limit(currentlyLoadedItems).snapshots().listen((QuerySnapshot snaps) {
      myItems = snaps.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        return Workout.formDoc(doc);
      }).toList();
      myItems.add(myItems);
    });
  }
```

the when user scrolls to bottom I do this:

```
loadMoreItems() {
  currentlyLoadedItems += 10;
  loadItems();
}
```

The problem with this solution is, I always need to load the already loaded items again. Because when I have loaded the first 10 items and I call `loadMoreItems()` I load the first 20 items, so I have loaded the first 10 items twice.

Is there a better way to update a query?

Comment: What you are trying to do is called "pagination", if that helps you Google search better for others who have already solved this.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is something more like "Infinite scroll" than "Pagination"